# Scanning files in C++ using its own standard libraries

Tags: c++

I want to know, or get a clue how to search through a directory in C++ with its own standard libraries or to see if it is possible at all.

Currently I have found several solution to searching directory, but they all use some external libraries such as this SO question:

[recursive folder scanning in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983376/recursive-folder-scanning-in-c)

How should we approach this?

Comment: You are only going to find platform specific solutions - or boost, I reckon. There are some C++14 filesystem things in the pipes though: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3505.html

Comment: Treat boost as a kind of standard, then you have Boost.Filesystem :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no filesystem facilities in the C++ standard. There is a technical specification for it which may be included in a future version of C++.

Until then, you will have to use platform specific functions or a library that wraps them. Apparently the new proposal is almost the same as boost's API, so I recommend using boost even if it's ubiquitousness wasn't good enough reason already.

Comment: Does this differ from what I just said in the comments?

Comment: @doctorlove: You put an answer in a comment, and now you're complaining about someone making an answer?

Comment: Do you mean we should use WinAPI?

Comment: I think it would be best to elaborate on your answer and give more details, though I got the point

Comment: @MostafaTalebi If you are convinced that no one will ever want to port your code to another platform, using WinAPI is fine I suppose. I've never used it myself so I can't say how it compares to boost. I  just added a recommendation of boost slightly before your comment. Is there any detail still missing?

Comment: Anyway I got the point of writing wrappers if one wants to keep hold of its application memory manipulation. Thanks