# What's the order of deletion when I do "rm -rf data"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I accidentally did a `rm -rf data` in a huge directory. I exited immediately.

The directory has a simple structure (they are all date-keyed sub-directories, like 2015/07/06) but the directory is huge and I don't want to regenerate the whole thing.  If I knew how `rm` removed the files, I could find and regenerate just the missing ones.

How does `rm -rf` go about deleting files?

Comment: it's in the order of any wildcards you provide are matched, and otherwise by the order of the filenames encountered as the directory file is parsed.

Comment: Without checking I would guess this is inode/directory entry order. And the simplest way to figure out what is missing is likely to be to just walk it looking for what you expect to be there assuming you can do that.

Comment: Heh. Clearly off-topic question (not at all about software development -- if one were to argue that a question about how a tool is implemented is a software development question, couldn't *any* usage question be on-topic for that reason?), but a really great answer. Personally, I would have filed it at http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`rm` performs a depth-first search](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/remove.c#n411), walking the results of the `xfts_open` call.

FTS is the [standard](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html) means by which files are traversed in all the Linux tools.  You can write your own [fts consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983524/2908724), or trust the output from `find`, since it also uses [`xfts_open`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/ftsfind.c).

`find .` will list the files that exist.  You can then use your knowledge of the expected structure to reverse the list that are missing.

Alternatively, you can use [`debugfs`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files) to help you get at the files.